# Apple Magic Trackpad freezes when I tap with 3 or more fingers

Tags: magic-trackpad

I bought an Apple Magic Trackpad. The device is working out of the box on Ubuntu 11.04 64bit.

However, when I tap with 3 - or more - fingers the device stops working. It works again if I disconnect it and then connect it again. I've tried touchegg but it didn't work.

Is there any solution to disable 3 or more fingers for tapping?

Comment: Look at my comment at:
http://askubuntu.com/a/402120/233113 (answered by second comment of original post of this question as well)

Answer (score 0):

You have probably moved on but for anyone else who arrives here. Try `lsusb`, to find out what bluetooth dongle you have, people including myself have this issue with the "Cambridge.. " models. [See reference here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/862085).

I'm trying my second usb dongle now an "Integrated Systems" model and it seems to have even more problems than the Cambridge (Random disconnects/freezes).